# python script with month to activate

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to make a python script as folllowing:

If,  between october - march:  do something

The if condition shout only work from  oktober 2017 until march 2018

How can I do that?

regards
gwaag

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep


while True:
    sleep(0.1)
    now = datetime.now()
    dt1 = datetime(2017, 1, 7)
    dt2 = datetime(2018, 3, 20)


    if dt1 <= now  and now <  dt2:
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("not ok")`

Comment: still not working like this what is the problem??

Answer (score 0):

I have this and it is working for me. Python 2.7, Debian.

```
from datetime import datetime 
from time import sleep 

dt1 = datetime(2017, 1, 7)
dt2 = datetime(2018, 3, 20)

while True: 
    sleep(0.1)
    now = datetime.now()
    if dt1 <= now and now < dt2: 
        print("ok")
    else:
        print("not ok")
```